# Vector - Find angle between two vector that form a perpendicular vector

Tags: vectors

How does one find the angle between two non-zero vectors **a** and **b**, if only given that Len(b) = 2 * Len(**a**) && (2**a** - 5**b**) and (6**a** - **b**) are perpendicular.

As they are perpendicular: (2**a** - 5**b**).(6**a** - **b**) = 12 (a^2) - 32(a*b) + 5(b^2) = 0

How do I go forward?

Comment: There are several similar questions to this that you can find in the handy list of related questions at right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos (\hat{ab})=\dfrac{a.b}{\left\| a\right\|  \left\| b\right\| }$

$\left\| b\right\| =2 \left\| a\right\|$

$\cos (\hat{ab})=\frac{a\cdot b}{2 \left\| a\right\|  \left\| a\right\| }$

$12 \left\| a\right\| ^2-32 a\cdot b+5 \left\| b\right\| ^2=0$

$12 \left\| a\right\| ^2-32 a\cdot b+5 \left(\left\| 2a\right\|\right)^2=0$

$-32a\cdot b=-32\left\| a\right\|^2\to a\cdot b=\left\| a\right\|^2$

$\cos (\hat{ab})=\frac{\left\| a\right\|^2}{2 \left\| a\right\|^2   }=\frac12$

$\hat{ab}=\frac{\pi}{3}$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

hint : len(a)=|a|, len(b)=|b| and |b|=2|a|. Also vec(a) dot vec(b) = |a||b|cosx where x is the angle between them

Comment: I am aware of this function, but what I get from 2 (a^2) - 32(a*b) + 5(b^2) and  vec(b) = |a||b|cosx  is x=90deg. I think I am calculating the angle between (2a - 5b).(6a - b) or am I wrong?

Comment: you have to find the angle between vectors a and b which is x. In place of  a*b substitute |a||b|cos(x). Also, substitute |b|=2|a| in the equation you got and solve for cosx.